# Running a section of code again in Java

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner having some trouble. I have a `try-catch` block where the `try` portion tries to run a section of code and the `catch` portion runs different code if the `try` code throws any sort of error. It looks something like:

```
try {
    <code to try>
} catch(Exception e) {
    <various variable reassignments>
    <run "try" code again>  (what I don't know how to do)
}
```

I think this involves some sort of loop, which I am fairly familiar with using, but I don't know how I would format it to work in this scenario.

Comment: You could put the `code to try` in a separated method, and call it in the `try` block as well as in the `catch` block.

Comment: look into a while loop - have the try catch inside the while loop and continuously execute the try catch until it works

Comment: you need to try the code repeatedly until there is no exception? or are you satisfied with running the code once inside the catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This underlines a small architectural problem.

There's no implicit looping in `try`/`catch` blocks: you try and recover if an `Exception` is thrown.

What you can do is, from best to worst:

1. Place the `try` code in a method, parametrizable as needed so its behavior can change when invoked again. Then invoke that method with different arguments in the `try` and `catch` blocks.

   Note that in this case, the invocation in your `catch` block might throw that same `Exception` again, which you might assume is not recoverable at that point.
2. Use nested `try` / `catch` blocks, where you vary the procedure from your `try` block within a `try` block nested in your `catch` block.

   This is ok but less readable.

   Multiple nested `try` / `catch` blocks will severely reduce your readability though.
3. Place the whole `try` / `catch` in a loop whose break condition is defined in **all** terminations (otherwise you might be looping forever and logging tons of stack traces)

   This would be acceptable in theory but is usually the recipy for disaster over time.

Answer (score 4):

You could break the loop if successful, and stay in it in case of an exception:

```
while (true) {
    try {
         <code to try>
         break; // operations were successful, so leave the loop!
    } catch(Exception e) {
         <various variable reassignments>
         // do not break, i.e. run "try" code again
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but this is causing everything in my "catch" brackets to repeat over and over after a single error is detected. Would it be easier for me to post the entire program so you can take a look at what the problem might be?

Comment: Sure, that would help a lot! 
Although I don't believe that it would run over and over, since the entire try-block is wrapped in that loop. Consequently, the part inside `try` would be re-executed first (and a catch block if, and only if, a corresponding exception occurs **again**).

Comment: This is bad code most of the time. While(true) is rarely a good idea. If something failed the first time and a second time, most of the time this will just be an expensive infinite loop doing nothing and eventually flooding the log/console with the same error over and over and in the worst case freeze your computer or use cpu time for nothing. Exception are meant to prevent nonsense code that doesn't do what you want the program to do, and this does more or less the exact opposite, if the error correction doesn't function after the first error, it won't after doing it 50/infinte times.

Comment: Sure, when using `while (true)` in this context your exception handling code should definitely also contain a `break` statement under certain conditions, if only as a backup. You should take care to exit gracefully if something goes wrong, and `while (true)` is rather bad at exiting on its own.

Comment: Here is the link to the code I have written. It generates a set amount of random numbers within a set range. Try typing a really large number into the input or typing a letter. This is where the issue resides. https://www.mediafire.com/?ol91tq12l1991qz

Answer (score 2):

You can either place your entire `try/catch` block into a loop, or make a method call from the `try` and `catch`. Note that if you use a loop you'll need some logic in place to prevent an infinite loop if you throw an `Exception` every time, even after updating your variable values.

**Make a method call**

```
String arg = "foo";
try {
   Object.method(arg); // your code, taking your variable as an argument
} catch (Exception e){
   arg = "bar";        // update variable value
   Object.method(arg); // call your code again
}
```

**Use a loop**

```
while (true){
    try {
        // ... your code, which might throw an Exception
        break;  // break if there are no exceptions
    } catch (Exception e){
        // assign vars
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the `<code to try>` into a separate method. Call it inside both `try` and `catch`. This way you will achieve something like a single retry. Another option is to put the whole `try catch` into a `while` loop and control how many retries you want using a variable and depending on the result you could initialize different variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
boolean run = true;
while(run)
{
    try
    {
        // do action
        run = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // do whatever actions
        // when you want to break, set run = false
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is no exception - infinite loop?

Comment: the value of `run` can be changed in the `try` block, so no infinite loop

Comment: @sharonbn Woops. Added `run = false` in the `try` block. Nice catch.

Comment: Could also use `while(true)` and `break`.

Comment: @doublesharp I tend to avoid `break`'s since then nesting of loops or `switch` (which I use a lot) becomes problematic. But of course you're right in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can encase the entire try/catch into a for/while loop that will exit when the try successfully runs.

```
while (true) {
    try {
         <code to try>
         //exit on success
           } catch(Exception e) {
                 <various variable reassignments>                 
                   }
 }
```

Comment: while (false) ? are you serious??

Comment: Sorry lack of sleep, I was rushing.

Comment: the BIG question was how to do exit on success, but that's already answerded elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with `while` loop, And then if you didn't get to the `success = true` assignment and got to the `catch` section, do your coding and the `while` loop will run again the try-catch section.

For example:

```
boolean success = false;
while (!success) {
  try {
      <code to try>
      success = true;
      } catch(Exception e) {
        <various variable reassignments>
      }
}
```